# How to pass multiple command in one query?

Tags: sql, wpf

Hi all how can I write code below more simply? ... so two sql(OleDb) command in one query.

```
con.open();
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM Customers WHERE ID_C = 1";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Clone();
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM Books WHERE ID_B = 1";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Clone();
con.close();
```

Comment: Hi Vignesh Kumar, why you gave me minus (bad) point and no answer?

Comment: You've no way of knowing who gave you the negative.

Comment: What database are you targeting? And by the way: normally it is `DELETE FROM`, not `DELETE * FROM`.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you don't need the number of rows affected (returned by `ExecuteNonQuery`) you can simply put both commands in the same SQL separated by ";"

```
con.open();
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM Customers WHERE ID_C = 1; DELETE * FROM Books WHERE ID_B = 1";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.close();
```

Comment: I already tried this ... but ... it showed me an error ... Characters found after end of SQL statement.

Comment: @Takeshi sorry I missed your OleDb clarification, this targets SQL Server